# AngularJS: How to set one input value from another and have it go through validation as if it was user entered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I'm using angular 1.3.0rc2, and I'm trying to have an input field, on blur, set another input field as if it was user entered.

If there exists only a synchronous validator on the input I'm trying to set, and no debounce or async validators, things always seem to work as expected when I do something like:

```
myForm.username.$setViewValue('some value');
myForm.username.$render();
```

However, things don't seem to work as expected when either an async validator or debounce exists on the input I'm trying to set, and when the input I'm trying to set is in a currently invalid state.

I've created the following plunkr to demonstrate my woes. Try setting the value of "Full Name" and see what happens with the *Username* field, which I want to also be set **on blur** of the *Full Name* field. When the *Username* field is in an invalid state, changing the value of *Full Name* and then removing focus from the field does not update *Username* as I would expect.

http://plnkr.co/edit/h1hvf79W8ovqAlNLpBvS

So, my question is, how can I set one input field from another in such a way that it will work reliably and act as if the user themselves has entered this new input (thus running through validators and updating the model value accordingly)?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it should adjust the username when you blur the full name.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAQ9JznVKwuOChyM9Oin?p=preview)

[ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

**HTML**

```
Full Name:
<input name="fullName" ng-model="fullName" test-validator change-field="username" />
User Name:
<input name="username" ng-model="username" required />
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("testApp",[]).controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {  


}).directive('testValidator', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if(!ngModel) return;

      element.on('blur', function () {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });

      function read() {
        if(attrs.changeField) {
          var field = attrs.changeField;
          scope.myForm[field].$setViewValue(element.val());
          scope.myForm[field].$render();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for posting an answer. Unfortunately, your answer uses no asynchronous validation etc, and so does not solve the issue I have. I edited your plunker here by adding an async validator and the problem occurs again: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zvk6lnc1qRNWnpHmYWLP

Comment: There's a good chance I'm thinking of this wrong, but my assumption is that you want to have the user put their full name in, have them use that as their username, but before they do that, make a server request to insure that the username is not taken, and meets validation criteria? Give this a try though, see if it helps. http://plnkr.co/edit/dAD6sWmE9tOhBR1ONAnk?p=preview

Comment: Try clicking on then off the first input in your plunkr a couple of times when the second input becomes invalid ;) The other issue is that now my nice asyncValidator is tied to setting the element value in this particular way, which is less than ideal if I want to reuse it elsewhere.

Comment: My basic intention is to have one field update another **as if the user entered the value themselves**. This means that if the field is invalid, the model value pointed from ng-model should become undefined, as it does when the user enters invalid input to a field. This requirement is what led me to trying $setViewValue etc rather than just updating the model value of the username field when the Full Name field is blurred (which does not leave the model value undefined if it becomes invalid). I feel like this should be possible somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, So the basic problem we want to solve here is that having a user set an input that turns out to be invalid leads to the underlying model value being set to undefined, whereas programatically setting the input to an invalid state does not.

This was inconsistent, and so I was trying to find a way to circumvent that. It turns out that the resolution isn't as straightforward as hoped (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9295)

However, the reverse solution was proposed instead, which involves using `ngModelOptions` on the enclosing form (or per input but thats more hassle) with "allowInvalid" set to true. This means that invalid values will still be set to the model, rather than the model value being cleared in that case.

Given that the model is always set now regardless of validity, I can revert to a simpler means of programatically setting one field form another - simply setting the underlying model value, and it behaves identically to if a user set the value themselves :)

plunkr demonstration with an async validator on the second input again:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lkDN4qLbbkN79EmRrxsY?p=preview

see how the model ends up the same regardless of whether the second input value is set by hand or set form the first input, irrespective of validity and the sue of async validator, as desired :)